# Order with groups in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I want a help to order, in javascript, this rows in a table. Explaining: i want to order by sequence and group, it means, order by the sequence, but when is a field who has the group, order inside the group... My list:

```
  ID    SEQ  GROUP  NAME
    0   0    0      field1
    7   1    0      field2
    4   2    0      field3 
    2   3    0      field4 
    3   4    0      field5
    6   5    0      field6
    5   6    0      field7
    1   7    0      field8 
   15   1    2      field9
   12   2    2      field10
   11   3    2      field11
  14   14    10     field12
  18   13    8      field13
  19   14    8      field14
  13   13    10     field15
   8    8    0      field16 
   9    9    0      field17
  10   10    0      field18
  16   11    0      field19 
  17   12    0      field20
```

i want to be like this:

```
 ID    SEQ  GROUP  NAME
    0   0    0      field1
    7   1    0      field2
    4   2    0      field3 
    2   3    0      field4 
       15   1    2      field9   -> this field is from a group with ID = 2. 
       12   2    2      field10  -> this field is from a group with ID = 2. 
       11   3    2      field11  -> this field is from a group with ID = 2. 
    3   4    0      field5
    6   5    0      field6
    5   6    0      field7
    1   7    0      field8 
   8    8    0      field16 
   9    9    0      field17
  10   10    0      field18
        13   13      10     field15 -> this field is from a group with ID = 10. 
        14   14      10     field12 -> this field is from a group with ID = 10. 
  16   11    0      field19 
  17   12    0      field20
  18   13    8      field13
  19   14    8      field14
```

my js code is:

```
function Order()
{
    var rows = $('#tbs tr:not(:first)').detach();

    rows.sort(function (row1, row2) {
        return parseInt($(row1).find('td.seq').text()) - parseInt($(row2).find('td.seq').text());
    });

    rows.each(function () {
        console.log($(this).text() );
    });
}
```

The SEQ column is the order i want.

Someone who likes math here? lol..

regards!

Comment: what's your js code?

Comment: question updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to sort the given data by sequence first and then build a tree, because of the given groups. Then you need to traverse the tree for a sorted result.

```js
var data = [{ id: 0, seq: 0, group: 0, name: 'field1' }, { id: 7, seq: 1, group: 0, name: 'field2' }, { id: 4, seq: 2, group: 0, name: 'field3' }, { id: 2, seq: 3, group: 0, name: 'field4' }, { id: 3, seq: 4, group: 0, name: 'field5' }, { id: 6, seq: 5, group: 0, name: 'field6' }, { id: 5, seq: 6, group: 0, name: 'field7' }, { id: 1, seq: 7, group: 0, name: 'field8' }, { id: 15, seq: 1, group: 2, name: 'field9' }, { id: 12, seq: 2, group: 2, name: 'field10' }, { id: 11, seq: 3, group: 2, name: 'field11' }, { id: 14, seq: 14, group: 10, name: 'field12' }, { id: 18, seq: 13, group: 8, name: 'field13' }, { id: 19, seq: 14, group: 8, name: 'field14' }, { id: 13, seq: 13, group: 10, name: 'field15' }, { id: 8, seq: 8, group: 0, name: 'field16' }, { id: 9, seq: 9, group: 0, name: 'field17' }, { id: 10, seq: 10, group: 0, name: 'field18' }, { id: 16, seq: 11, group: 0, name: 'field19' }, { id: 17, seq: 12, group: 0, name: 'field20' }]
    .sort(function (a, b) { return a.seq - b.seq; }),
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            o[a.id] = { data: a, children: o[a.id] && o[a.id].children };
            if (a.group === root) {
                r.push(o[a.id]);
            } else {
                o[a.group] = o[a.group] || {};
                o[a.group].children = o[a.group].children || [];
                o[a.group].children.push(o[a.id]);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data, 0),
    sorted = tree.reduce(function traverse(r, a) {
        return r.concat(a.data, (a.children || []).reduce(traverse, []));
    }, []);

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```